# Access SQL - Update statement can't set field to NULL. Says

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I've inherited an application that uses Access as the database. I have a field (Date/Time, not required) with some values I need to set to null after a specific date.

To update it I have a [little program](https://gist.github.com/inabahare/8987ae8ae68ecbfc11920ef564dd5b06) that runs the query and tells me how many rows affected. (Access isn't installed on the server, the mdb is constantly locked. So I can't download, update, replace. But I can use a simple VB program)

Anyway I need to set some values to null, and to do that I use the following query:

```
UPDATE [AppPosting] SET [approvedTime] = NULL WHERE [approvedTime] >= #25/10/2022 00:00:00#
```

Running it gives me "82 affected rows", and running it again gives me the same amount of affected rows. If I open access and look in the (local copy of the) database I can see they haven't update. If I run the same query in access also get 82 affected rows, but they're also set to null.

So what gives? My update says it updates through OleDbConnection, but doesn't update. Whereas through access it says it updated, and actually updates?

Comment: Why do you have VBA tag if code is VB (.Net or VB6 or VBScript?). When run in Access are you running a query object or VBA action SQL?

Comment: Because sometimes reading is hard :v
When I run it in access I do it through Create -> Query Design -> SQL View -> Run

Comment: No need to switch to SQLView. Only thing I can think of is it has something to do with the international date structure. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html